# Xamarin Form: Unable to see CarouselView after update the Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, view, carousel

I have searched the web, I can see there is a CarouselView on Xamarin Assembly Versions: 2.0.0.0. I updated my Xamarin.Forms package to 2.3.1.114. When I opened up the Assembly Browser, I couldn't see the CarouselView under Xamarin.Forms. Is there a requirement to use this View.

I am currently having a profile of :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.. I haven't checked "Show Prerelease" checkbox at the bottom of the nuget